# How to add search for contacts like demo app using iron-list

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to implement a simple contacts list the [one shown here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list?view=demo:demo/selection.html&active=iron-list). I setup my data source and everything as given in that example. Now if i want to add a search box or dropdown at the top of the page so that what user selects a drop-down menu or types something in the search box, how do I filter my results. For example: If the user types "GRI" in search box i need to show up all contacts with firstname matching "GRI". Any ideas how do i implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you show your contacts list like this:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{filteredContacts}}" as="contact">
   <div>{{contact.name}}</div>
</template>
```

And you have list that looks like this:

```
...
...
<script>
filteredContacts: {
   type: Array,
   value: [],
}
unfilteredContacts: {
   type: Array,
   value: [{name:"testcontact1"}, {name: "testcontact2"}],
}

//this should be called when input changes on your text input
onFilterTextInputChange : function(){
   this.filteredContacts = []; //we empty the array so that old results won't be shown
   var filterString = this.$.myFilterTextInput.value(); // we retrieve the text from the text input that we are supposed to filter on
   for(var i=0;i<this.unfilteredContacts.length; i++)
   {
      //Here you make your filtering logics (the example below will only show contacts whose name match exactly what you type in the input field)
      var contact = this.unfilteredContacts[i];
      if(contact.name == filterString)
         this.push("filteredContacts", contact);
   }
}
</script>
```

Note, the code above might not work to just copy-paste. There might be some syntax errors, but you should get the drift on how you can proceed. :)